# SVN: Cannot mix repository and working copy sources error

Tags: svn

When I run the following command

```
svn copy http://host/svn/someproject/trunk \ http://host/svn/someproject/tags/uteeni -m"adding externals"
```

I get a svn:

```
Cannot mix repository and working copy sources error
```

reply, what am I doing wrong?
The tags folder has been added to the project and the trunk as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Removal of "\" fixed the issue.
Here is my command which worked:

```
svn copy from_url to_url -m "my comments for tag"
```

Answer (score 7):

It happens when paths are incorrect.
Also helps to use //server:8080/... instead of //server/... if using http:
And '\' is not needed if you type command in 1 line.

Answer (score 3):

I have also seen this problem when I've pasted the command from MS Word.  Somehow I believe Word changed the formatting of some of the characters in the text.  Retyping an identical command from scratch solved this problem.

Comment: I had the same problem while pasting from PowerPoint. I've tried retyping only parts pf the command, and it worked when I've replaced the "-m" part, so I guess MS Office tries to be helpful by changing the minus sign to something else.

Answer (score 2):

Is that backslash supposed to be in your question?

Otherwise it's probably to do with your svn client being a different version that your server. I've seen that fail with a similar error message before.

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure, but if I remove it I get svn: '/svn/someproject/!svn/bc/23/tags' path not found

Comment: found the problem, tags folder created inside trunk... damn

Answer (score 0):

Try

.... -m "adding externals"

I think you need a space after -m (make sure the tags directory exists)

Or execute the command on the server

svn copy file:///svn/someproject/trunk file:///svn/someproject/tags/uteeni -m "adding externals"